# How to make locally pushed array global javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, erpnext, frappe

I have array initially declared in global scope as an empty array
then inside a function callback. I have to push response message elements to this array.

But I need to get this update array outside callback of function

```js
 var array = []
 frappe.call({
        method: "frappe.client.get_list",
        args: {
            doctype: 'Attendance',

       filters: [['attendance_date', '>=', values.from_date],
                ['attendance_date', '<=', values.to_date]

            ]
        },
        "callback": function (response) {
            console.log(response.message)
            for (var i in response.message) {
                frappe.call({
                    method: "frappe.client.get_value",
                    args: {
                        doctype: 'Attendance',
                        fieldname: ['branch'],
                    filters: { 'name': ['=', response.message[i].name] }

                    },
                    "callback": function (data) {
                        frappe.call({
                            method: "frappe.client.get_value",
                            args: {
                                doctype: 'Medical Crew Salaries',
                                fieldname: ['total'],
                             filters: { 'cost_center': ['=',data.message.branch]}
                            },
                             "callback": function (r) {
                                    array.push({ branch: data.message.branch, total: r.message.total })

                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
    }
    })
console.log(array.length)
var result=[]
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
if (!res[value.branch]) {
    res[value.branch] = { branch: data.message.branch, total: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.branch])
  }
  res[value.branch].total += r.message.total;
  return res;
}, {});
console.log(result)
frappe.model.with_doctype('Journal Entry', function() {
        var journal_entry = frappe.model.get_new_doc('Journal Entry');
        for(var c in result){
                var journalentry_account= frappe.model.add_child(journal_entry, 'accounts');
                    journalentry_account.debit_in_account_currency=result[c].total
                    journalentry_account.cost_center=result[c].branch
            
        }
                frappe.set_route('Form', 'Journal Entry', journal_entry.name);      
                        })
```

The reason why I need to do that is that I need to loop trough this array outside, the first for loop array.

Comment: The array variable is scoped inside your function, so you could either declare it outside of the function or pass it to another function, where you will do your looping logic.

Comment: out side existing for loop because inside  first for loop iteration run twice

Comment: If the callback is not called synchronously, but later, then you should only expect the array to be populated during the callback execution: you cannot expect an array to have the values *now*, when the array will only get populated in the *future*.

Comment: @trincot no it is called synchronously

Comment: So what is the code that is not doing what you want? Can you show the code where you do this outside the existing loop -- I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Best is to show the code that is failing. Is `console.log(array.length)` outputting the expected size?

Comment: array.length should be the array length after pushing response elements; I just need to loop through this array but outside the already existing for loop it causes wrong total values inside array.reduce .. code updated

Comment: *"...should be the array length after..."*: yes, I understand that. My question is: does it currently output what it should output? Your updated code has 20 opening braces and 21 closing braces. Can you also take care to properly indent your code?

Comment: @trincot array.length outputs zero outside callback function.inside callback it works fine..alse code updated again thanks

Comment: That is why I asked this earlier on: it proves that your callbacks execute *asynchronously*, and not synchronously as you stated. NB/ the code is not properly indented. Please update.

Comment: @Zeinab Mohammed, This is so common question, I saw many questions like that, A month ago I answer [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831144/object-is-not-returning-the-value-outside-of-function-but-returning-it-inside-th/66831928#66831928), You may find something helpful...

Comment: @trincot so what is the solution regarding that?

Comment: That's a whole subject. Read the reference at the top.

Comment: @trincot thanks so much I have restructured my code so it works fine now I appreciate your responses

Comment: @Nur Thanks I was great reference